# The GCD of Certain Multiples of Coprimes

Tags: divisibility

Let $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$, and let $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$. Is there anything that we can conclude about $\gcd(pn,qnm)$? I am asking this because it might help me answer the truth of the statement: if $\gamma | \gcd(pn,qnm)$ (with $n,m$ coprime), then $\gamma | pqn$.

Comment: All we can say is that $$\gcd (pn , qnm) = n \gcd (p , qm)$$

Comment: I see $n$ is common in $pn$ and $qnm$ , so $n$  is $\gcd$ right??

Comment: @Fawad $n$ is a common divisor, but it might not be the largest one.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gamma | \gcd(pn ,qnm)$ , in particular it is a common divisor of $pn$ and $qnm$. Hence
$$\gamma | pn \ \Longrightarrow \ \gamma |pqn$$